# Automatic pop up appears on clicking on custom button

Tags: visualforce, community, custom-button, napili, extension

I have a Url custom button, and for some record types, a pop-up appears on Napili Community after clicking that button.

Accept Button url:
    /XXXX/X/acceptreferral?recordId={!Service_Request__c.Id}

Vf page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Service_Request__c" extensions="acceptReferalForPartnerExtension" action="{!AcceptReferal}">

<script>
    if({!errorFlag}){
        alert('Only Referral Service Requests with Request Status = "Awaiting Response" can be accepted');
        var str = '{!serviceRequestId}';
        window.top.location.href = '/Partner/s/detail/' + str;
    }
</script>
```

Extension:

```
public class acceptReferalForPartnerExtension {
public List<Service_Request__c> serviceRequestList;
public List<Case_Responsibility__c> caseResInsert = new List<Case_Responsibility__c>(); 
public List<Case> caseList = new List<Case>();
public List<Case_Responsibility__c> resList = new List<Case_Responsibility__c>();
public List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailList;
public boolean errorFlag {get;set;}
public string serviceRequestId{get;set;}

public acceptReferalForPartnerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
    errorFlag = false;

    serviceRequestId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    system.debug('Id '+serviceRequestId);
    List<Service_Request__c> serviceRequest = [select id, Request_Status__c,Referring_Business_Unit__c,Referring_Caseworker__c,Name, RecordType.DeveloperName, OwnerId, Category__c, Referring_Unit_Manager__c 
        from Service_Request__c where id =:serviceRequestId LIMIT 1];
 serviceRequestList = new List<Service_Request__c>();
    Service_Request__c sR = new Service_Request__c();

    // AC 8931.01.01 (BR 8931.01)
    if(serviceRequest[0].Request_Status__c == 'Awaiting Response' && (serviceRequest[0].RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Service' || 
            serviceRequest[0].RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Program_Generic' || serviceRequest[0].RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Program_IFBS' ||  
            serviceRequest[0].RecordType.DeveloperName == 'ServiceProvider_Program_IFBS' || serviceRequest[0].RecordType.DeveloperName == 'ServiceProvider_Program_IFP' || 
            serviceRequest[0].RecordType.DeveloperName == 'ServiceProvider_Program_Generic' || serviceRequest[0].RecordType.DeveloperName == 'ServiceProvider_FGC' || 
            serviceRequest[0].RecordType.DeveloperName == 'ServiceProvider_Service' || serviceRequest[0].RecordType.DeveloperName == 'ServiceProvider_Case_Coordination') && 
            serviceRequest != null && serviceRequest.Size() > 0){

        sR.Id = serviceRequest[0].id;
        sR.Request_Status__c = 'Engaged';
        sR.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId(); 
        serviceRequestList.add(sR);
   }
 public PageReference AcceptReferal(){
    if(!errorFlag){
        try {
            update serviceRequestList;
            update resList;
            update caseList;
            insert caseResInsert;

        } catch(Exception e){}

        if(emailList != null && emailList.size() > 0) {
                Messaging.sendEmail(emailList);
        }

        // Redirect the user back to the original page
        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/'+serviceRequestId );
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg;
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Pop-up appears on Accept button:
[image]

Comment: Share the button code.

Comment: Accept Button url: /XXXX/X/acceptreferral?recordId={!Service_Request__c.Id} button URL the above vf page and extension related to this button.